# Clickable BaseAdapter rows?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-adapter

I want to use a method for a `BaseAdapter` similar to this:

```
public void onClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class).putExtra(chatroomName) 
    //Putting the text in the listview into the intent
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Here's what I have for the adapter already:

```
    chat.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return messages.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
            }
            Date d = new Date();
            TextView seeTexts = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            TextView usernameTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById((android.R.id.text1));
            seeTexts.setText(messages.get(position).getMessage());
            String messageInfo = messages.get(position).getUsername() + " - " + messages.get(position).getSendTime();
            usernameTime.setText(messageInfo);
            usernameTime.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            seeTexts.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            seeTexts.setTextSize(16);
            usernameTime.setTextSize(13);


            return convertView;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you use ListView? Why not use onItemClickListener of ListVIew

Comment: please share you BaseAdapter

Comment: How do I use onItemClickListener?

Comment: use implement add code into onItemClickListener  in Activity or Fragment......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a custom Listview in your application.Please try this code:

```
  ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 

      }
   });
```

Comment: So do I get rid of the BaseAdapter? Also is the listView mutable(can you add more cells)?

Comment: No,not necessary you can use it accordingly,yes  ListView is designed in such way,you can always add more cells.